# Need to get each "floatvalue" entry from json using js

Tags: javascript, json

There is a json code.  In it, you need to get "floatvalue" from each entry. I couldn't understand this note, please help me.

```
[
    {
        "iteminfo": {
            "a": "24726444009",
            "d": "162704505716002445",
            "floatvalue": 0.06065493822097778
        }
    },
    {
        "iteminfo": {
            "a": "24726350664",
            "d": "16595412847277410541",
            "floatvalue": 0.06316522508859634
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: "you need to" - no, i don't need to.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to extract the floatValue from each objcet

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "iteminfo": {
            "a": "24726444009",
            "d": "162704505716002445",
            "floatvalue": 0.06065493822097778
        }
    },
    {
        "iteminfo": {
            "a": "24726350664",
            "d": "16595412847277410541",
            "floatvalue": 0.06316522508859634
        }
    }
]

const floatValues = arr.map(item => item.iteminfo.floatvalue)

console.log(floatValues)
```